# Plot silhouette in R, each cluster a different texture

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis

I was doing a cluster analysis and would like to validate the clustering result with silhouette plots. Learned from others' code, the plot function plot the silhouette for me, and when I specify 3 colors for my plot, it gave me what I want, however, if I specify density and angle using the same way, all plots change at the same time. I would like to give different clusters with different textures. Is there any way of doing it?

Here is the code and the result (please ignore the low silhouette width value):

```
dE2 <- dissE^2 #dissimilarity matrix
sw2 <- silhouette(clust.fit$clustering, dE2)
pdf("silhouette plot.pdf") 
sil_plot <- plot(sw2, col=c("#CEEAE6","#291B4F","#FCD42B"), 
                 angle = c(0,45,90), density = c(5,10,20), main = "silhouette plot")
dev.off()
```

[image: Silhouette plot from my code]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are specifying three values for `angle` and `density` - one for each cluster - but you must specify a value for every point.  Your three values are just being recycled so they appear all over the place in your plot. Instead, try:

```
sil_plot <- plot(sw2, col=c("#CEEAE6","#291B4F","#FCD42B"), 
                 angle = c(0,45,90)[clust.fit$clustering], 
                 density = c(5,10,20)[clust.fit$clustering], 
                 main = "silhouette plot")
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I tried the method you provided, however, I still got the same old plot. Your explanation makes sense to me, but do you know why col works but not angle and density? Thank you.